# Effective version of Krasner's lemma

Tags: polynomials, reference-request, p-adic-number-theory

Let $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}_p[x]$ be two monic $p$-adic polynomials of the same degree $n$ and write $$f=x^n +a_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots + a_0, \qquad g=x^n+b_{n-1}x^{n-1} + \cdots b_0.$$

Let $K_f, K_g$ denote the corresponding splitting fields. Is there an explicit constant $C$ (depending on $n$ and $p$ probably) such that if $|a_i-b_i|<C$ for all $0 \leqslant i \leqslant n-1$, then $K_f \cong K_g$?

I feel like an ineffective version should be given by Krasner's lemma (although this may assume irreducibility). I'm looking to use it for an explicit numerical example and hence would like a bound - I don't care how sharp it is.

Comment: Of course no try with $m$ large and $f(x)=x^{p-1} - p^{(p-1)m},g(x)=x^{p-1} +  p^{(p-1)m} $ whose splitting fields are $\Bbb{Q}_p$ and $\Bbb{Q}_p(\zeta_{2 (p-1)})$. If $f \in \Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ is monic of degree $n$ then $p^{m (n-1)}f(p^{-m} x)\equiv x^n \bmod p^m$. To overcome that problem you may assume $|a_0| \ge R$.

Comment: Thank you for this counterexample. If we do assume $|a_0|$ is sufficiently large as you suggest, is the statement now true?

Comment: If $f ,g\in \Bbb{Z}_p[x]$ is monic of degree $\le n$ and $|f(0)| \ge R$ then there is a uniform constant $C$. Not sure how to extend to $f,g \in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ monic of degee $\le n$ and $|f(0)|\ge R$.

Comment: @reuns $\mathbb{Z}_p$ coefficients are enough for me. Is there a formula/ reference for $C$ in this case?